# Equivalent of OpenLayers 2 ol.Layer.Text in ol3 (to show POIs)

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2

I have this OpenLayers 2 code that I want to convert to OpenLayers 3:

```
var pois = new ol.Layer.Text(
    "My POIs",
    { location:"/media/pois.txt",
      projection: ...
    }
);
map.addLayers([
    pois
]);
```

The `.txt` file is a tab-separated file with the following columns:

`lat lon title description icon iconSize iconOffset`

What is the equivalent [ol.source](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.html) to achieve the same effect, and do I need to change anything in the input file?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately ol.Layer.Text is not a valid source in Openlayers 3 although it looks like it could be quite useful. Instead you have to define on ol.layer.Vector and assign the source to a geojson file. I'm sure if you search you can find a utility that will convert a csv to valid geojson for this purpose. [This is a pretty neat example.](http://geojson.io/)

Sample code below:

```
    // create a vector source that loads a Countries GeoJSON file
    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        url: 'assets/data/countries.geojson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    });

    // a vector layer to render the Countries source
    var countriesLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        title: 'Countries',
        type: 'overlay',  // used to filter layer types
        id: nameGen(new Date().getTime()),  // timestamp generator for id
        visible: false,
        source: vectorSource,
        style: session.countryStyle
    });

map.addLayer(countriesLayer);
```

Also here is a sample geojson file:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
       "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            21.09375,
            53.74871079689897
          ],
          [
            48.515625,
            61.77312286453148
          ],
          [
            85.78125,
            52.26815737376817
          ]
        ]
       }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -111.09374999999999,
          65.94647177615738
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -95.625,
          47.98992166741417
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This basically works, with `visible: true`, and an id instead of calling `nameGen`. I need to figure out how to implement icons. `property.graphic` pointing to a PNG wasn't rendered - https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/5322.